# Create a new DIV within an existing DIV using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to create a new div within an existing div using JavaScript?

**I'd like the following to happen:**

1. Create a new div with `class="three"` and put it inside `div class="one"`.
2. Create a new div with `class="text"` and put it inside `class="three"` and add the text 'this is sample text'.

**The end result should look like this:**

[image]

```css
.two{
  width:700px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.three{
  width:300px;
  height: 200px;
  transform: translate(50%, -250%);
  background-color: red;
}
.text{
  text-align: right;
  transform: translate(-5%, 440%);
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// get a reference to the first div by using its class as search path
var divOne = document.querySelector('.one');
// create a new element
var divThree= document.createElement('DIV');
// add a class 'three' to a newly created element
divThree.classList.add('three');
// and add a newly created element to divOne
divOne.appendChild(divThree);

// now create a div for text, set its class to 'text' and append it to divThree
var txt = document.createElement('DIV');
txt.classList.add('text');
txt.innerHTML = 'this is sample text';
divThree.appendChild(txt);
```

```css
.two{
  width:700px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.three{
  width:300px;
  height: 200px;
  transform: translate(50%, -250%);
  background-color: red;
}
.text{
  text-align: right;
  transform: translate(-5%, 440%);
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If it's just text you can also use `txt.innerText`

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you can write the below code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".one").html("<div class='three'><div class='text'>This is a sample text</div><div>");
});
```